Is there is any information available on how llama index calculates a score for its correctness evaluator?
I have been developing a chatbot which uses llama-2 and llama index to build the knowledge base and was planning on using the llama index evaluators to test how good it is. The problem is, I am struggling to understand how exactly it calculates a score for correctness as well as a few of the other evaluators (faithfulness & relevancy).
I have looked at the documentation and only seem to be able to find general definitions of what the evaluators do. I would like to understand how exactly they are calculated so I can understand my results better. Would appreciate any direction of where I can find this information
